# Not able to solve $\int\limits_1^n \frac{g(x)}{x^{p+1}} \mathrm dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

If $p=\frac{7}{8}$ then what should be the value of $\displaystyle\int\limits_1^n \frac{g(x)}{x^{p+1}} \mathrm dx $
when $$g(x) = x \log x \quad \text{or} \quad g(x) = \frac{x}{\log x}? $$

Wondering which way to proceed?

1. an algebraic substitution,
2. partial fractions,
3. integration by parts, or
4. reduction formulae.

Please don't suggest something like ("Learn basic Calculus first" etc).
Kindly help by solving if possible because I'm out of touch with calculus for nearly 15 yrs.

Comment: Yes U r correct...I meant $\int_1^ng(x)/x^{p+1}dx$

Comment: For the second one, $g(x)=x/\log x$, the integrand is not integrable due to the behaviour at the bound $1$.

Comment: @Sigur: you have edited it wrongly..please revert it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{g(x)}{x^{p+1}}=\frac{x\log x}{x^{p+1}}=\frac{\log x}{x^p}$$

By parts:

$$u=\frac1{x^p}\;,\;\;u'=-\frac p{x^{p+1}}\\v'=\log x\;,\;\;v=x\log x-x$$

Thus:

$$\int\limits_1^n\frac{\log x}{x^p}dx=\left.\left(\frac{\log x}{x^{p-1}}-\frac1{x^{p-1}}\right)\right|_1^n+p\int\limits_1^n\frac{\log x}{x^p}dx-p\int\limits_1^n\frac1{x^p}dx\ldots\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks @DonA but Whats the ultimate value?

Comment: It would be more direct to differentiate $\log x$ in the integration by parts. When $p\neq 1$.

Comment: You calculate it, @ArnabDutta . Do some effort, pass from side to side...if you get stuck somewhere write back.

Comment: Julien is right: it'd be better (well, or simpler, easier...) to put $\,u=\log x\ldots$ etc.